# Invalid Method Decleration - New to Methods

Tags: java, methods

I am using a Constructor:

```
Donor(String lastName, String firstName, String type, int age, double minutes)
```

And am aware that I must name it the same as the public class it resides in, but when I move my curly braces so that it is encompassed by the public Donor class I am met with several errors.

My code is as follows:

```
public class Program5
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Arrays.sort(Donor, new lastNameComparator());
        for (int i = 0; i < donor.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Donor[i].getLastName());
        }

        Arrays.sort(Donor, new firstNameComparator());
        for (int i = 0; i < donor.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Donor[i].getFirstName());
        }

        Arrays.sort(Donor, new typeComparator());
        for (int i = 0; i < donor.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Donor[i].getType());
        }

        Arrays.sort(Donor, new ageComparator());
        for (int i = 0; i < donor.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Donor[i].getAge());
        }

        Arrays.sort(Donor, new minutesComparator());
        for (int i = 0; i < donor.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Donor[i].getMinutes());
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Donor> donorCSVList(String filePath) throws IOException
    {
        ArrayList<Donor> list = new ArrayList<Donor>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
        while (scan.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            String [] lineArray = line.split(",");
            list.add(new Donor(lineArray[0], lineArray[1], lineArray[2], lineArray[3], lineArray[4]));
        }
    }

    public class Donor
    {
        private String lastName;
        private String firstName;
        private String type;
        private int age;
        private double minutes;
    }

    public void Donor()
    {
        super();
        type = "Not assigned";
        age = 0;
        minutes = 0.0;

    }

    Donor(String lastName, String firstName, String type, int age, double minutes)
    {
        super(lastName, firstName);
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.type = type;
        this.age = age;
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public double setMinutes()
    {
        return minutes;
    }

    public void getMinutes(double minutes)
    {
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

    public class lastNameComparator implements Comparator
    {
        public String compare(Donor o1, Donor o2)
        {
            String lastName1 = o1.getLastName();
            String lastName2 = o2.getLastName();
            return lastName1.compareTo(lastName2);
        }
    }

    public class firstNameComparator implements Comparator
    {
        public String compare(Donor o1, Donor o2)
        {
            String firsName1 = o1.getFirstName();
            String firstName2 = o2.getFirstName();
            return firstName1.compareTo(firstName2);
        }
    }

    public class typeComparator implements Comparator
    {

        public string compare(Donor o1, Donor o2)
        {
            String type1 = o1.getType();
            String type2 = o2.getType();
            return type1.compareTo(type2);
        }
    }

    public class ageComparator implements Comparator
    {
        public int compare(Donor o1, Date o2)
        {
            int age1 = o1.getAge();
            int age2 = o2.getAge();
            //return o2.getAge() - o1.getAge();
        }
    }

    public class minutesComparator implements Comparator
    {
        public double compare(Donor o1, Donor o2)
        {
            double minutes1 = o1.getMinutes();
            double minutes2 = o2.getMinutes();
            //return o2.getMinutes() - o1.getMinutes();
        }
    }
}
```

And my error is:

```
Program5.java:66: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
        Donor(String lastName, String firstName, String type, int age, double minutes)
```

Comment: Which line is the error on? The error message should have the line number.

Comment: I have updated the question to more properly reflect the current problem I now face

Comment: @snitchyc When posting example code on StackOverflow, we ask that you strip away all unnecessary lines. [Create a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with the fewest possible lines that still demonstrates your problem. As a side-benefit, in doing so you may well answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you've misplaced most of the contents of your `Donor` class. What you have is structured like this:

```
public class Donor
{
    private String lastName;
}

public String getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}
```

While what you want is more like this:

```
public class Donor
{
    private String lastName;

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

All the members of the class need to be inside the curly braces that delimit the contents of the class, not just the fields.

Additionally you seem to be calling `super()` with arguments in a constructor that's meant for a class that doesn't have a superclass with a constructor that takes arguments. That doesn't make sense.

Lastly you probably meant to make your `Donor` constructor public:

```
public Donor(String lastName, ...
```

Comment: All classes except Object have a superclass. Calling `super()` for it may be pointless, but it is legal.

Comment: I have moved the ending curly brace that encompasses the public class Donor to hold all my getter and setter methods but that only increase my errors. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: @Douglas: I guess you're more semantically correct but what I was getting at was the `super()` call with arguments.

Comment: @snitchyc yes--your main should error because you use `Donor[i]` but Donor is not an array; it is a type.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be too many errors in this example. I have summarized a few:

- Donor class should be outside the main class. Also, it should not be public, Java file can have only one public class (which is Program5 in our case).
- All comparator classes incorrectly implement `compare()` method. They need to be parametrized with Type (`<T>`) and `compare()` should have `@Override` annotation.
- `public void Donor()` is actually a method. If we want it to be a constructor then we need to remove `void`.
- `super()` calls are not needed in any of the constructors as `Donor` class does not extend any class.
- In `while` loop of `donorCSVList` method, we need to check the number of elements in `lineArray` before accessing by their indices. It may lead to `arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

`Donor` is a class but in `main` you're treating it like a variable. It looks like what you intended was to read some input with `donorCSVList` and then sort the result of that and output it. To do that, you have to actually call `donorCSVList` and use the return value, like this:

```
ArrayList<Donor> donors = donorCSVList("someFileNameHere");
Arrays.sort(donors, new lastNameComparator());
```

...except that `ArrayList` is not the same thing as an array, so `Arrays.sort` won't accept it. You'll need to use `Collections.sort` instead.